# Operator $A\ \text{bounded from below}\iff A^*\ \text{surjective}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $A\in H'$ a bounded operator and $A^*$ its adjoint. $A$ is called bounded from below if there exists a $b>0$, such that $b ||h||\le ||Ah||, \forall h\in H$. Then how can one establish that
$$A\ \text{bounded from below}\iff A^*\ \text{surjective}$$
The hint given is to use closed range theorem that $Ran(A)$ is closed iff $Ran(A^*)$ is closed. But I am not sure how to connect closedness and surjectivity. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do the following:
Since $A$ is bounded below and $H$ is complete, you have that $Ran(A)$ is closed. Which means that $Ran(A)$ is a Hilbert space.

Again by being bounded below, it follows that $A_0\colon H\to Ran(A)$, the restriction of $A$ into it's range, is a linear isomorphism (bicontinious as well).
Therefore you have that $A_0^* \colon Ran(A)' \to H'$  is also a linear isomorphism of $Ran(A)' = Ran(A)$ into $H'=H$.

And I think you can prove that $A_0^*$ it is only $A^*$ restricted to $Ran(A)$. Therefore, $A^*$, may no longer be injective, but it is surely surjective.

For the other way around, I think you can do something similar.
If $A^*$ is surjective then define $H_0\doteq \ker (A^*)^\perp $, which is a Hilbert space, and $A^*_0\colon H_0\to H$, which is a linear isomorphism since $A^*$ is surjective.

Then $(A_0^*)^*\colon H'\to H_0'$ is a linear isomorphism (bicontinous as always), therefore it is bounded below.
Once again, since $H$ and $H_0$ are Hilbert spaces,it follows that $H'=H$ and $H_0' = H_0\subset H$.

And I think you can prove that $(A^*_0)^*$ coincides with $A^{**} = A$. And you're done.

Comment: This seems to work even if $A$ is an operator between arbitrary Banach spaces. However, this only establishes one implication.

Comment: Actually no, I use that $Ran(A)' = Ran(A)$ and $H'=H$ which is not true in general for Banach Spaces

Comment: But you are right, tis is only one implication, for some reason I thought the other one was easier, but I'll think about it, if I come up with something I'll edit my post to add it

Comment: Just added the solution for the converse

Comment: It doesn't matter. $A_0^*$ is still an isomorphism and $A^*$ is the composition of the restriction map $\operatorname{codom}(A)'\to \operatorname{rng}(A)'$ with $A^*_0$, so it is an epimorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition is still true in the wider context of Banach spaces. But I'm not sure whether the following proof can be simplified in the context of Hilbert spaces.

> *Proposition.* For Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, a bounded operator $A: X\to Y$ is also bounded below *iff* the adjoint $A^*: Y^*\to X^*$, defined as $A^*: f\mapsto f\circ A$, is surjective.

*Proof.* Consider the induced map $\tilde{A}: X\to \overline{\text{ran}(A)}$ and its adjoint $\tilde{A}^*: \overline{\text{ran}(A)}^*\to X^*$. Since $A$ is bounded, so are $\tilde{A}$, $\tilde{A}^*$ and $A^*$. $\text{Ker}(A^*)=\{f\in Y^*: f|_{\text{ran}(A)}=0\}=\text{ran}(A)^\perp=\overline{\text{ran}(A)}^\perp$
is therefore closed in $Y^*$, and map $A^*$ induces an injective bounded operator on the quotient space
$\alpha: Y^*\Big/\overline{\text{ran}(A)}^\perp \to X^*$.
Recall the well-known consequence of the Hahn-Banach Theorem that there is a Banach space isometric isomorphism
$\beta:\overline{\text{ran}(A)}^* \to Y^*\Big/\overline{\text{ran}(A)}^\perp$. Then it can be verified that
$\tilde{A}^*=\alpha\circ \beta$, and so $\tilde{A}^*$ is always injective and bounded.

If $A^*$ is surjective.
Then, map $\alpha$, induced by $A^*$, is a Banach space isomorphism *onto* $X^*$. Hence $\tilde{A}^*$ is a composition of Banach space isomorphisms.
But $\tilde{A}^*$ is an isomorphism *iff* $\tilde{A}$ is an isomorphism. Hence $\tilde{A}$ is bounded below, and so is $A$.

If $A$ is bounded below, then $\text{ran}(A)=\overline{\text{ran}(A)}$ and $A$ is injective. Hence $\tilde{A}$ is a bounded bijection. By open mapping theorem, it is then a Banach space isomorphism. Hence its adjoint $\tilde{A}^*$ is also an isomorphism *onto* $X^*$. Hence $A^*$ is surjective.
$\square$

**Reference.** In Conway's *Functional Analysis* textbook, there is a detailed proof of the equivalence between $\text{ran}(A)$ being closed and $\text{ran}(A^*)$ being closed (Theorem-VI.1.10 on p.169-170). But surjectivity here enables us to skip the messy middle steps involving the weak* topology.